# What is the equivalent of this code in c#

Tags: c#, java

```
List<Double> constants = new ArrayList<Double>() {{
            add(1.4);
            add(0.4);
            add(1.2);
            add(2.4);
            add(4.2);
            add(5);
            add(6.0);
            add(7.0);           
          }};
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In C# 3.0 or greater,

```
var constants = new List<double> { 1.4, 0.4, 1.2, 2.4, 4.2, 5D, 6D, 7D };
```

`constants`is [implicitly typed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx) to`List<double>`with the`var`keyword. The list is initialized (by putting the numbers in braces) using the [collection-initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) syntax.

This is equivalent to (C# 2.0 or greater):

```
List<double> constants = new List<double>();
constants.Add(1.4);
constants.Add(0.4);
constants.Add(1.2);
constants.Add(2.4);
constants.Add(4.2);
constants.Add(5D);
constants.Add(6D);
constants.Add(7D);
```

You can leave out the`D`s, but I prefer to be explicit with numeric literals.

On another note, if this really represented a list of unnamed constants, it would be good to use an immutable collection such as [`ReadOnlyCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx). For example:

```
var constants = new List<double>{1.4, 0.4, 1.2, 2.4, 4.2, 5, 6, 7}.AsReadOnly();
```

Comment: You don't need to do 5D, it is inferred.

Comment: @Yuriy: No, it's not inferred.  It's implicitly converted.

Answer (score 7):

Like this:

```
List<Double> constants = new List<Double>() { 1.4, 0.4, ... };
```

This uses a new feature in C# 3.0.

If you're still using VS2005, you can write

```
List<Double> constants = new List<Double>(new double[] { 1.4, 0.4, ... });
```

This is not quite the same.

The first line is transformed by the compiler into a series of `Add` calls on the list.

The second line creates a `double[]` array and passes it to the `List<T>` constructor, which copies it to the list.

Answer (score 4):

The above is simply a static list initialisation, so the equivalent in C# would be:

```
new List<Double>(){ 1.4, 0.4 }
```

Note that the Java code above actually creates a *new inner class which is a subclass of ArrayList*, and then initialises it. You wouldn't normally have to worry about this, but it's worth knowing (it will have an implicit `this` pointer, and cause headaches when serialising)

Answer (score 2):

```
List<double> constants = new List<double>() { 1.4, 0.4, 1.2, 2.4, 4.2, 5, 6, 7 };
```

Answer (score 1):

Using an inner class is probably not the best way to do it in Java. You'd probably want to do something like

`List<Double> constants = Arrays.asList(new Double[]{1.4,0.4,1.2,2.4,4.2,5.0,6.0,7.0});`